# Algorithm to check if (overlapping) intervals can be found to cover a bigger interval

Tags: java, algorithm, intervals

Suppose that you're given a list of intervals. Assume that we somehow can ask each interval what it's start and end is (f.ex. list.get(i).getStart() and list.get(i).getEnd()). In addition to the list, you're given a starting integer and an ending integer. I want to know if there can be found some intervals from this list to cover our 'domain-interval' [start,end].

*An example:*

```
Input: list{[1,5],[2,7],[7,9]}, start: 1, end: 9; 
Output: TRUE.

But the same list with start 0 and end 9, will result in FALSE.
```

Now, I'm wondering how I could do this efficiently. Hints (or answers) are welcome!

Thanks.

Comment: StackOverflow isn't a code-writing service. The purpose of this site is to help with specific code issues. So what code have you written, and what issues are you having with that code?

Comment: I don't have a code, because I have no clue how to start with this. Maybe merging intervals will help, but then again I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Discard intervals that end before your start or start after your end. In your example there are no such intervals, but had `[-3,0]` or `[11,17]` been there, they would have been discarded. Sort the remaining intervals by start. As far as possible join the remaining intervals into bigger intervals. So `[1,5],[2,7]` are first joined into `[1,7]`, which in turn is joined with `[7,9]` to form `[1,9]`. If the resulting interval covers your domain interval, the answer was yes.

As far as I understand, your list would cover `start: 1, end: 9`, I don’t know why you expect `false`.

Comment: Indeed, it should be TRUE. I'll edit that, thank you. I have one more question. When merging the intervals, should I create a new interval, add it to the list and delete the subintervals, or is it more efficient to somehow modify the start and end of one of the subintervals at its current position (and delete the other one)?

Comment: I wouldn't worry much about efficiency, but do what gives the most natural code. A possible compromise might be putting the new intervals into a new list and leaving the original lust unchanged. @Zachary